# Oracle UNPIVOT and SYSDATE giving weird results

Tags: oracle, date-arithmetic, unpivot

I am trying to transpose columns to rows using query similar to the following...

```
WITH 
query AS
(
    SELECT    SYSDATE AS SomeDate,
              'One' AS One,
              'Two' AS Two, 
              'Three' AS Three,
              'Four' AS Four,
              'Five' AS Five
        FROM dual
),
up_query AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM query
    UNPIVOT 
    ( 
     NUM FOR DUMMY 
     IN 
     ( 
      One AS 'One',
      Two AS 'Two',
      Three AS 'Three',
      Four AS 'Four',
      Five AS 'Five'
     )
    )
)
SELECT SYSDATE, b.*
  FROM up_query  b;
```

I was expecting SomeDate to reflect SYSDATE for the resulting rows...
But this is the result I am getting:

```
SYSDATE   SOMEDATE       DUMMY  NUM
09-DEC-11 09-DEC-07      One    One
09-DEC-11 09-DEC-07      Two    Two
09-DEC-11 09-DEC-07      Three  Three
09-DEC-11 09-DEC-07      Four   Four
09-DEC-11 09-DEC-07      Five   Five
```

Why is the SOMEDATE 4 years earlier than SYSDATE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mark mentioned in his answer, this is a bug in Oracle 11.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.2 versions atleast.

However as per [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2011/03/09/oracle-bug-unpivot-returns-wrong-data-for-non-unpivoted-columns/) article there is a workaround if you are stuck with the Oracle versions mentioned above, which is to **convert the date to varchar format and then convert it back to date datatype.**

So the query should now be:

```
WITH 
query AS
(
    SELECT     TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'RRRRMMDD') AS SomeDate,
              'One' AS One,
              'Two' AS Two, 
              'Three' AS Three,
              'Four' AS Four,
              'Five' AS Five
        FROM dual
),
up_query AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM query
    UNPIVOT 
    ( 
     NUM FOR DUMMY 
     IN 
     ( 
      One AS 'One',
      Two AS 'Two',
      Three AS 'Three',
      Four AS 'Four',
      Five AS 'Five'
     )
    )
)
SELECT SYSDATE, TO_DATE(SomeDate, 'RRRRMMDD') AS ActualSomeDate, b.*, 
  FROM up_query  b;
```

Comment: You can also fix it by replacing `SYSDATE` with `cast(SYSDATE as date)`.  Apparently SYSDATE is a special data type that is not always a DATE.  See this Ask Tom thread: http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:910228941137#47403557344816    Also, you can see this weird type conversion with this query: `select dump(sysdate), dump(cast(sysdate as date)) from dual;`

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug in 11.2.0.2.  I can reproduce your results on Linux x86-64, 11.2.0.2.

But, on 11.2.0.3, on Linux x86-64, I get:

```
$ sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.3.0 Production on Sat Dec 10 01:20:32 2011

Copyright (c) 1982, 2011, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.3.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, Automatic Storage Management, OLAP,
Data Mining and Real Application Testing options

SQL> WITH
  2  query AS
  3  (
  4      SELECT    SYSDATE AS SomeDate,
  5                'One' AS One,
  6                'Two' AS Two,
  7                'Three' AS Three,
  8                'Four' AS Four,
  9                'Five' AS Five
 10          FROM dual
 11  ),
 12  up_query AS
 13  (
 14      SELECT *
 15      FROM query
 16      UNPIVOT
 17      (
 18       NUM FOR DUMMY
 19       IN
 20       (
 21        One AS 'One',
 22        Two AS 'Two',
 23        Three AS 'Three',
 24        Four AS 'Four',
 25        Five AS 'Five'
 26       )
 27      )
)
 28   29  SELECT SYSDATE, b.*
 30    FROM up_query  b;

SYSDATE   SOMEDATE  DUMMY NUM
--------- --------- ----- -----
10-DEC-11 10-DEC-11 One   One
10-DEC-11 10-DEC-11 Two   Two
10-DEC-11 10-DEC-11 Three Three
10-DEC-11 10-DEC-11 Four  Four
10-DEC-11 10-DEC-11 Five  Five
```

Comment: You are right. Its a bug in Oracle 11.2.0.1 and 11.2.0.2 versions atleast. However there is a solution. Check my answer.